# android: EXDATE format when adding a calendar event

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-calendar, android-event

Can someone explain how to use `EXDATE` when adding event to android calendar? The documentation is pretty unclear about the format in which the `EXDATE` should be put.
I tried many formats, these are some of them:

```
values.put(Events.EXDATE, "TZID=Europe/London:20130116T080000");
values.put(Events.EXDATE, "20130116T080000Z");
values.put(Events.EXDATE, "20130116T080000");
values.put(Events.EXDATE, "20130116");
```

but none of them works.
Any idea how to make an event not appear on a particular date, if by the `RRULE` it should appear?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct format is:

`values.put(Events.EXDATE, "20130116T080000Z");`

However you must ensure that it is in UTC time.  I was having the same problem starting from PST, so I just had to add 8 hours to get it to work.

Comment: Thanks! That was my problem, it wasn't correctly changed in UTC

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the @kee23's answer, the next variant is valid for multiple **EXDATE** values:

```
contentValues.put(CalendarContract.Events.EXDATE, "20130116T080000Z,20130118T080000Z");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding on top of @kee23's excellent and correct answer:

I just got aware that in android, you *can not* persist EXDATEs to an event with *endless recurrences*, say `RRULE:FREQ=DAILY`. You need to limit the occurrences, as in `RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=600`.

This is not documented by google and there is no error message if you try to persist endless recurrences with EXDATEs. It just silently dropped RRULE and DURATION in my case.