# Android CalendarContract recurring event with exception dates

Tags: android, android-calendar, recurring-events, calendarcontract

I can't find a way to insert exception dates to a recurring event.

### Context

I'm parsing an .ics file (ical format) with an event **with success**.
Here is the .ics

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Google Inc//Google Calendar 70.9054//EN
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:PUBLISH
X-WR-CALNAME:TESTING
X-WR-TIMEZONE:Europe/Amsterdam
X-WR-CALDESC:
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Europe/Amsterdam
X-LIC-LOCATION:Europe/Amsterdam
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
TZOFFSETFROM:+0100
TZOFFSETTO:+0200
TZNAME:CEST
DTSTART:19700329T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=3;BYDAY=-1SU
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZOFFSETFROM:+0200
TZOFFSETTO:+0100
TZNAME:CET
DTSTART:19701025T030000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=10;BYDAY=-1SU
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Amsterdam:20140425T103000
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Amsterdam:20140425T113000
RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=FR
EXDATE;TZID=Europe/Amsterdam:20140516T103000
EXDATE;TZID=Europe/Amsterdam:20140502T103000
DTSTAMP:20140425T090449Z
UID:3bb37doi3qcuaih3t03ns0q9jo@google.com
ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;CN=TESTIN
 G;X-NUM-GUESTS=0:mailto:domain.com_o300s@group.calendar.google.com
CREATED:20140425T090310Z
DESCRIPTION:
LAST-MODIFIED:20140425T090427Z
LOCATION:
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:my-recurring-event-with-ex
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

The event is then inserted into the Android calendar via the CalendarContract API.

dtstart: 20140425T103000
dtend: 20140425T113000
rrule: FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=FR

### Problem: exclusion date(s)

If I now query my calendar I will see an event on every friday starting on the 25 april 2014.

The problem is that I also need to exclude some dates (See ical: 2 may 2014 & 16 may 2014)

#### Attempt 1

I tried inserting the exdate for the 16 may only using the EXDATE field like this:
[android: EXDATE format when adding a calendar event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14522393/android-exdate-format-when-adding-a-calendar-event?rq=1)
But that didn't work and based on the android calendar source code it is not even used.

#### Attempt 2

I tried to insert the exception using the CONTENT_EXCEPTION_URI
Via this so post: [Make exception event from original recurring event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16915993/make-exception-event-from-original-recurring-event)
Google calendar code: https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_calendar/blob/master/src/com/android/calendar/EventInfoFragment.java#L1401

```
ContentValues values2 = new ContentValues();
       
values2.put(CalendarContract.Events.ORIGINAL_INSTANCE_TIME, event.getAsString(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART));
values2.put(CalendarContract.Events.STATUS, CalendarContract.Events.STATUS_CANCELED);

Uri.Builder eventUriBuilder = CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_EXCEPTION_URI.buildUpon();
eventUriBuilder.appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER, "true");
eventUriBuilder.appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, accountName);
eventUriBuilder.appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, accountType);
ContentUris.appendId(eventUriBuilder, dbId);
Uri uriex = cr.insert(eventUriBuilder.build(), values2);
```

uriex is always null.

#### Attempt 3

I tried inserting a new event with a link to its original event like in the google calendar code for deleting a single entry of a recurring event
https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_calendar/blob/master/src/com/android/calendar/DeleteEventHelper.java#L361

### Q

Does anybody knows how to deal with the CalendarContract API for exceptions in a recurring event?

Answer (score 0):

i have queried my own devices calendar database.

```
 select _ID,exdate from events where exdate is not null
```

it contains for example exdate="20090103T093000Z,20110101T093000Z"
so the date must be formatted as utc ("Z")

```
> and based on the android calendar source code it (the field exdate) 
> is not event used.
```

did you analyse the after-boot-event, when android calculates/updates the (event-)instances from the events?

Comment: I think I tried adding them like that too. I guess I will have to try again. And for the second part, no I didn't, I have looked into the source of the Calendar App from Google mainly